# Convert string time to seconds

Tags: date, time, conversion, uptime

I'm receiving an uptime in this format:

```
167h58m10.586582048s
```

I want to transform it to seconds and discard the fraction part.
I know `awk` could do that if only the received string had the same separator. That's not the case.

How could I convert that to seconds?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"only the received string had the same separator"* - POSIX awk should permit an extended regular expression field separator such as `[hm.]` I think?

Comment: Read `man date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I try this:

```
$ echo "167h58m10.586582048s" | awk -F '[hm.]' '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'
604690
```

It works great.

Thanks @steeldriver. I didn't know about that.

I found this good [article about Field Separators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html) in `awk`.